# Getting "Size tap targets appropriately" warning on an element which is not tappable at all

Tags: pagespeed

On my following page, """qa-mobile.proptiger-ws.com/noida-real-estate""", my current UX score is 92/100.

There are total 5 warning regarding "Size Tap Targets Appropriately".

### The tap target Sikka Kaamya Greens and 9 others are close to other tap targets [see screenshot](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=qa-mobile.proptiger-ws.com%2Fnoida-real-estate#).

### The tap target Sector 10 Noida Extension and 9 others are close to other tap targets.

### The tap target 2, 3 & 4 BHK Apts and 9 others are close to other tap targets.

### The tap target 22.70 L - 43.09 L and 8 others are close to other tap targets.

### The tap target Filters(0) and 1 others are close to other tap targets [see screenshot](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=qa-mobile.proptiger-ws.com%2Fnoida-real-estate#).

The problem is that 4 of them are not buttons or links, neither I've attached any click event on them via javascript/jquery.

Any solution would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. The click event was on the parent element and was affecting the children too. Altering the design and detaching the click-able areas in such a way that they are independent was the solution that worked for me.